# Pull "last access" information on projects from Google Cloud Platform (GCP)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud

I have a large number of projects to handle on Google Cloud Platform. To clean them up, I want to pull a list of all projects incl. information on usage so I can filter and identify e.g. outdated projects.

Especially info on "last access" would help a lot. I couldn't find a way yet to pull a datetime variable giving me the last use of e.g. "data access" or "configuration" activity.

Any idea on how to perform such a query? Even alternative ways of determining recent activity within projects would help. Most used resources are BigQuery, ComputeEngine, Buckets.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You can achieve this through:

- [Audit Logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/audit) Or
- [Cloud Asset Inventory](https://cloud.google.com/asset-inventory/docs/overview) (better than audit logs for your case).

You will have the ability to view activity at project level or at folder/organization level.

---

Edit:

Including the `Cloud Asset Inventory` query that [@nordlicht.22](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11318429/nordlicht-22) created to solve the issue:

```
gcloud asset search-all-resources \
  --scope='projects/{ProjectID}' \
  --query='updateTime > 1643155200' \
  --order-by='createTime DESC' \
  --limit='1'`
```

Comment: Thanks! Cloud Asset Inventory seems to do the magic.

Comment: @nordlicht.22 You're welcome. I have edited this answer and included the query that you used :)